# How to write Angular Clean Code using Subscribe Method?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material, angular8

How do I write clean code in Angular for subscribing? Due to the Asynchronous nature of Angular Typescript, we have to write a `processItems()` method in Different places in the code. One location, without a dialog box warning, and a location Within the Subscribe of Dialog Box Closing.

Is there any way to centralize the code in one place?

**Currently:**

```
public validateProductOrder(){
    if (this.product.cost > 1000){
        this.runMaterialDialogBoxWarning();
    }
    else if (this.product.addressType == 'International'){
        this.sendConfirmationEmailCode();
        this.runMaterialDialogBoxWarning();
    }
    else{
        this.processItems();
    }

public processItems(){
   this.processOrderForm();
   this.deliverShipping();
}


runMaterialDialogBoxWarning(){

    materialDialogBoxRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result=> {
        if (data.submit == true){
            this.processItems();   // this is another location we have to write processItems();
        });
```

**Ideal Method:**

```
public validateProductOrder(){
    if (this.product.cost > 1000){
        this.runMaterialDialogBoxWarning();
        this.processItems();
    }
    else if (this.product.addressType == 'International'){
        this.sendConfirmationEmailCode();
        this.runMaterialDialogBoxWarning();
        this.processItems();

    }
    else{
        this.processItems();
    }
```

If the ideal method is not possible, then that's fine, just curious. Doing things with subscribing may make it hard to track items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to create an observable which mimics the response returned by the dialog, and then subscribe to the result at one place.

This way, the method `processItems` will be called at only one place. Here is an example to achieve this:

```js
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

// rest of the code

public validateProductOrder() {
  let obs: Observable<any>;

  if (this.product.cost > 1000) {
    obs = this.runMaterialDialogBoxWarning();
  } else if (this.product.addressType == 'International') {
    this.sendConfirmationEmailCode();
    obs = this.runMaterialDialogBoxWarning();
  } else {
    // Assign an observable with immediate response here.
    obs = of({submit: true});
  }

  // Subscribe to the observable here.
  obs.subscribe(data => {
    if (data.submit) {
      this.processItems();
    }
  });
}

public processItems() {
  this.processOrderForm();
  this.deliverShipping();
}

runMaterialDialogBoxWarning() {
  return materialDialogBoxRef.afterClosed();
}
```